# C# combox index to textbox list

Tags: c#

So I am trying to make a name lister. What I have is when user enters name into combobox and presses button "Add Name" the name is added to its list. Then if user presses button "list names" all names in the combobox list are displayed into the text box.

I was able to code it to do the first part but can't figure out or find a code that takes the names from combobox and displays them in the text box. Please help. Because what I want is when the "List Names" button is pressed, it adds a list of the names from the combobox into the text box using a loop.

The photo is what it looks like just before pressing the "list names" button. And then here is my code so far. I'm writing this code in C#.

```cs
//My code for btnExit.
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

//My code for btnAdd.
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cboName.Items.Add(cboName.Text);
    cboName.Text = "";
    cboName.Focus();
}

//My code for btnList.
private void btnList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

My photo

[image: my list image]

Comment: Take a look at documentation on combobox and if there is a property to list the items it holds. Do a foreach or for on it and you will get what you are looking for.

Comment: i'll try that give me one moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the items from combobox:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cboName.Items.Count; i++)
{
     string value = cboName.GetItemText(cboName.Items[i]); 
     TEXTBOX.AppendText(value );
     TEXTBOX.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: tried adding that code to it it doesn't seem to pull the names over to it, still shows the word "Names" instead of displaying all names does that code need to include the txtName.text somewhere in it thats what i named the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //We will put all your entered strings here.

        for (int x=0; x< comboBox1.Items.Count; x++)
        {
            sb.Append(comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[x]) + Environment.NewLine); //I added new line for better reading since you have scrollbar
        }
        textBox1.Text = sb.ToString(); //Display the result on your textbox
    }
```